# Share BMP with ShareActionProvider?

Tags: java, android, image, bmp

In my app I am trying to share a BMP with the ShareActionProvider. It is not working. Am I doing it wrong or do I need to convert it into a PNG (I do not want to deal with files). If so how can I do it? THanks.

```
Bitmap bmp = qrUtil.create(WIFIQRCODE, pref2);
                isCodeGenerated = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/png");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmp);
                provider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` should be a URI pointing to the image file that you want to use; you can't just add a `Bitmap` there. You should do something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "img.jpg"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri.toString());
```

This will change depending on the actual location of your image, but that's the general idea.

Comment: My Bitmap is a variable, how can I do that?

Comment: You would need to write it to the filesystem and keep track of where you write it to.

Comment: Oh I wanted to do it so I am not saving files

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible.

Comment: Could I do Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(bmp))); ?

Comment: I'm telling you honestly that you cannot do this. The receiver of this intent expects a URI to be attached as an extra labeled `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`.